# Nodejs, mongoose and Qunit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, qunit

I have been at this for hours and its like banging my head into a brick wall.

I have a node.js server application that uses mongoose to store data.

Now this all works amazingly but my problem is when I try and use Qunit to test my code I can get me mongoose save function to fire.

This is my unit test class.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var User = require('C:/SVN/RPGMMO/Server/Users/User');

QUnit.config.testTimeout = 50000;

QUnit.module("User", {
    setup: function() {
        user = new User();
        ok(user != undefined, "Test Data Created");
    },
    teardown: function() {
        user = undefined;
        ok(user == undefined, "Test Data Deleted");
    }
});

test("Create User", function() {
    var user = new User({
        name: 'test_user',
        email: 'blah'
    });
    user.setPassword('test');

    user.save(function(err, result) {
        util.log("saving");
        if (err) throw err;
        ok (result, "Created User")
    });
});
```

But when I run this test the user.save is never fired, only the setup and teardown is run.

Could anyone point out where am going wrong.

Am new to Quint on server side.

Regards
Iain